# windows phone 8.1 app registration through facebook

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, facebook-login

I want to integrate facebook login in my app for registration i am following [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-81-FaceBook-87eb2f69) link but not able to understand how to get the Windows Store ID in step 1.2.. can anyone please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to put the code

```
Uri _callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```

somewhere in your app, for example at the end of App.OnLaunched() method, then put a breakpoint after it, run the app and examine the returned value.

Comment: But can you please solve one more issue. as I said I am following the above link, and now I am trying to fetch user profile and other details and also want the logout button to work. but after logging in i go into my app but  I am unable to see logout button.

Answer (score 2):

So the windows store id can be retrieved in two ways. One is programatically by calling this method

```
Uri _callbackUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```

And the other way is to login to your microsoft account which you would have registered in dev.windows.com then perfom the following steps

1. Navigate to dashboard.
2. Select the app for which you want to integrate the FB login.(If you haven't registered an app in this account yet then I recommend you do it. Because once you do that and login via Visual studio the above mentioned URI method will return same store Id)
3. Then navigate to that app and on the left you will see a options like Acquistions,Analytics etc. there click on App Management and inside that click on App Identity.
4. In the app identity page you can find a field name **Package SID** which is your store id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for help.. But please tell me If i want to use the first method how can I programatically call that method. I mean from where..

Comment: You can add it anywhere in your code. But best would be to call it in the constructor of the class where you are performing the login.

Comment: If it worked you can mark it as answer so that it helps others facing the same problem as well.